# Design a grid to update data dynamically

Tags: django, datagrid, grid

I am highly apologetic beforehand for my question sans coding terminology. Many of you might have seen or used google calendar. I am trying to design a similar web app(not a calendar but shares the same concept of 2 dimensional grid and a click on any grid should lead to a popup where I fill it with data that goes into that particular grid without necessity of refreshing the page).An option of editing the grid data or deleting them should also be there.

I am unaware of the essentials that are needed to design such webpages. What language(or library) is used to design such applications ? Where do I start? A detailed answer about what to study or how to approach it would be helpful. I think I am quite adept with basics of django. I intend to use this app in a django based website. Is that possible ?

I have tried to search for similar questions on SO but they were using quite advanced terms I cant make anything of.

Comment: Chris's answer is great and explains the tools you need. Since you're familiar with django, I would suggest you try a proof of concept without AJAX. Try your hand at jQuery/javascript popups, but use regular form submits to edit/delete. When you're confortable with that, build in the ajax functionality (the django views should practically be unchanged) which would handle asynchronously posting the data and updating / deleting HTML elements based on the server response.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have been learning javascript and css. I am trying out a few css frameworks like blueprint and 978.gs. Its interesting to find that grid system is actually used to give format to webpages and not just for making tables as I asked in the question. @chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up a "grid" is nothing more than floating elements with CSS. There's 1001 tutorials on how to do that online that can be found easily with your trusty friend, Google.

The "click and it pops up with additional info" stuff is JavaScript, and specifically the fetch "without refresh" is AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). Again there's a ton of information online about that subject as well.

If this is all Greek to you, I'd suggest learning about all the topics I've mentioned in great detail. You can start at some place like Wikipedia to get an overview, but then, look up unfamiliar concepts you come across in Google, or spend some time on Amazon or your local bookstore and find some books on the topics.

Once you have a little familiarity with all that, you almost certainly won't do it from scratch. There's a ton of cross-browser concerns and boilerplate code that serves as simply places to introduce bugs. You'll want to choose a JavaScript framework to handle all the cruft for you, and jQuery would be an excellent choice. It's extremely easy to use and is pretty much the most popular JS framework out there, so you'll experience no shortages in tutorials or help when you need it.

If you run into specific issues, you can return here to ask specific questions, but for the most part, it's up to you to glean what you can from the vast resource that is the Internet and/or books, and just play. Try stuff out, and learn from your mistakes. That's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched for existing jQuery or Sencha plugins that would provide the functionality you want?

If you need to design your own for some reason, then you would need some combination of the following technologies: HTML, JavaScript, Some JavaScript Library would be helpful (example jQuery).

To draw your calendar like widget you can use an HTML Table. Be careful and aware of paddings, margins, borders etc. for the table as this can be a headache. For the popup you can use something like jQuery impromptu or SimpleModal.

Comment: the OP just used a calendar as an example. He's not trying to make a calendar.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect the same. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Django pluggable application which allows to perform standard CRUD operations with grid rows. Also it is possible to define custom operations both at client-side and server-side:
https://github.com/Dmitri-Sintsov/django-jinja-knockout

There is sample project with some models that are presented as grids, both non-AJAX datatables and AJAX datatables:
https://github.com/Dmitri-Sintsov/djk-sample

It uses jQuery / underscore.js / knockout.js at client-side - small libraries which loads quickly even at slower connections.